# Neglected constant curvature difference surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

What are some surfaces where $ \kappa_1-\kappa_2$ is constant?  On a sphere where all are umbilical points.. is a special case.

For the $ \kappa_1+\kappa_2$ = constant case we have DeLaunay and Minimal surfaces.

$ \kappa_1,\kappa_2$ are the principal curvatures.

EDIT1:

In the limited number of numerical integrations done so far as a surface of revolution I obtain a symmetrical U shaped meridian between vertical asymptote planes in one case and two cuspidal ring edges in another.

Comment: This is a special case of a (linear) Weingarten surface, you might have some luck searching for those.

Comment: $ a \kappa_1 + b \kappa_2 =$ constant?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Had no luck with Weingarten surface search.

Answer (score 2):

Another trivial case is a cylinder with $\kappa_{1}=\dfrac{1}{r}$ and $\kappa_{2}=0$.

How about another variation with $2\kappa_{1}-\kappa_{2}=0$?

> Mylar balloon
>   \begin{align*}
>   \left(
>      \begin{array}{c}
>        x \\
>        y \\
>        z \\
>      \end{array}
>    \right)
>   &= 
>   r\left(
>      \begin{array}{c}
>        \text{cn} \left( u,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \cos v \\[5pt]
>        \text{cn} \left( u,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \sin v \\[5pt]
>        \sqrt{2} \left[
>                   E \left(
>                       \text{am} \left( u,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) ,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
>                     \right)
>                   -\frac{1}{2} u
>                 \right]
>      \end{array}
>    \right) \\
>   \kappa_{1} &= \frac{1}{2r} \, \text{cn} \left( u,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \\
>   \kappa_{2} &= \frac{1}{r} \, \text{cn} \left( u,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
> \end{align*}

Comment: Interesting. Curvature quotient rather than difference is constant here in the Elastica. The balloon has no circumferential stress, but  only along its meridian

Comment: @Narasimham See also another article [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.07566.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for remembering and for the reference. DeLaunay Unduloids have been known;$\kappa_1/\kappa_2= 2 $  is Balloon case and  $\kappa_1/\kappa_2= 1/2 $  is a common cycloid swept on x-axis.. I suppose unduloids have Gauss $K$ positive and negative in their parts.  So  $ a \kappa_1+ b  \kappa_2= con $ is not another class at least for a surface of revolution. I was also looking for non-rotation symmetric surfaces..