# 2D function for a party balloon

Tags: geometry, functions

I searched some time over the web and this mathematics site without finding what I am searching for.

What I need is the 2D function of a simple balloon. Not an hot air balloon but a simple single-colored party balloon (without the knot at the bottom). Has anyone an idea for this?

Here an example for what I mean:

[image: balloon]

I only want the shape, not a complex function including the light effects, the knot or something else.

Of course, the upper part is just half of a circle, but I need some more exact function for the lower part.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It depends on the natural or flaccid shape of the balloon.  Sausage balloon has elongated natural shape.  By the way, there's mathematical formula for [mylar balloon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mylar_balloon_(geometry))  and see also [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868863/neglected-constant-curvature-difference-surfaces/1869181#1869181).

Comment: How about using a vertical ellipse for the lower half?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no physics here, but the polar graph
$$
r =  1 + 0.375\operatorname{sech}(2.75(\theta + \tfrac{\pi}{2}))
$$
is a good visual match for your image:

[image: A profile of a fake balloon]

---

**Edit**: I hit on the parameters after a fortuitously small number of tries. Here are images showing the profiles if the "width" or "height" (respectively) of the sech hump is varied:

[image: Balloon: Varying the width of the hump]
[image: Balloon: Varying the height of the hump]

Comment: Nice. You might provide some small examples  showing how tuning the two parameters modifies the shape.

Comment: The first graph is exactly what I need, but when trying it out there is just kind of a circle as you can see here:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=8d8e2c27bcaa121d6ee0de4b98774bb4&title=Polar%20Graphs&theme=blue&i0=1%2B0.375sech(2.75(%CE%B8%2BPi%2F2))&i1=0&i2=2Pi&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1

What am I doing wrong - just a hint?

Comment: Oh, I have found my mistake: Use -PI..+PI for angle, not 0..2PI. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

The physics dictating the shape at the bottom is subtle, but assume for simplicity that the shape is a bit more than a semicircle on top, and a parabola at the bottom.

Then if we take the center of the circle to be the origin, there are two parameters to describe the balloon:  The angle past a semicircle that is still in the "upper" part, and the circle radius.  I will take the radius to be one; I assume you can scale for a larger balloon.

The angle $\theta$ beyond a semicircle is a bit arbitrary but it looks from the picture that it it goes $30^\circ$ past the semicircle. Then The parabola 
goes thru the points $(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.-\frac12)$ and $(+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.-\frac12)$, and has slope $\sqrt{3}$ at $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  This specifies the parabola unicles, so the shape of the balloon is
$$
y = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccccl} 
+\sqrt{1-x^2} &,& -\sqrt{1-x^2} & \mbox{when }& -1 \leq x \leq -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
+\sqrt{1-x^2} &,& \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x^2 - \frac{4+3\sqrt{3}}{8} & \mbox{when }& 
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} < x < \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
+\sqrt{1-x^2} &,& -\sqrt{1-x^2} &\mbox{when }&  x \leq +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \leq 1 
\end{array} \right.
$$

Comment: Nice and easy function. I realized it, but it is not exactly what I need. Sorry, but thanks for your entry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A 2D graph of a balloon:
$$2x^2 + y^2 - 3\sin(y) - 7 = 0.$$
Also, if you want a line under the balloon, try
$$\sqrt{2\cos(0.5y + 2.6)} + x -0.2 = 0.$$
Hint: type in GeoGebra.